# Search server 2010 not indexing ascx/aspx files

Tags: 2010, search

I have set up an instance of Microsoft Search Server 2010, and am trying to get it to index ASCX, ASPX, Master and CSHTML files, but it's not currently working. The search application seems to find the files OK and add them to it's index, including file attributes, but the content of the files is not indexed so attempting to search for something inside one of the files does not work.

So far I have:

- Added the file types within the File Types list within SharePoint administration
- Added the extensions within HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office Server\14.0\Search\Setup\ContentIndexCommon\Filters\Extension\ with the default ifilter of 0FF1CE14-002C-0000-0000-000000000000
- Added entries for these extensions within HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office Server\14.0\Search\Setup\Filters with custom mime types

After each of these changes I restarted the osearch14 service, and restarted IIS.

Can anybody suggest anything I may have missed, or anything else I could try to ensure the content of these files is indexed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Site and content owners may be able choose whether or not to include
> content in search results. By default, the content of a site will
> appear in search results. If a site owner or administrator specifies
> that the site content will not appear in search results, then the
> other search results settings such as those for lists, libraries, ASPX
> pages, and columns would not have any effect.
>
> Similarly, if a site
> administrator or owner prevents list or library content from appearing
> in search results, then excluding columns would not have any effect.
> It is important to know what settings are inherited from higher levels
> in order to plan effectively

**Choose whether to include the contents of ASPX pages in search results**

> As a site owner you can control whether the content of ASPX pages are
> included in search results. When you create a site, many content pages
> are created automatically, for example, default.aspx, allitems.aspx
> for your Web Part gallery, editform.aspx as an edit form for your
> announcements list, and several others. You can also create custom
> ASPX pages. By default, when a Web Part displayed on an ASPX page uses
> information from a list or library that contains restricted
> permissions, otherwise known as fine-grained permissions, none of the
> content in any of the ASPX pages on the site is included in search
> results. This prevents non-authorized users from viewing content.
>
> For example, let’s say there are five documents displayed in a Shared
> Documents Web Part on a team site where there are 50 members. One of
> the documents has restricted permissions; only a few people are
> allowed to see it. Content is automatically hidden from that site in
> search results so that the content from that document does not appear
> when users conduct a search. This prevents the content of the ASPX
> page from accidentally being exposed to people who are not supposed to
> see it.
>
> You have the option of ignoring this setting to display all content in
> search results regardless of permissions. In this case, all content
> will appear in the search results, but unauthorized users may not be
> able to access the actual documents. Another option is to not to
> include any ASPX content in search results, regardless of the
> permissions set on it.
>
> **1**.Navigate to the site for which you want to control the Web Parts in search results.
>
> **2**.Click Site Actions, and then click Site Settings.
>
> **3**.Under Site Administration, click Search and offline availability.
>
> **4**.In the Indexing ASPX Page Content section, under This site does not contain fine-grained permissions. Specify the site’s ASPX page
> indexing behavior , select one of the following options:

**Do not index Web Parts if this site contains fine-grained permissions**

> When permissions of the ASPX page are different from the parent site,
> then none of content on the site appears in search results.

**Always index all Web Parts on this site**

> Show content of all ASPX pages in the site appear in search results
> regardless of how permissions are set.

**Never index any Web Parts on this site**

> Hide content of all ASPX pages in the site in search results
> regardless of how permissions are set.

but after noting the above i recommend you look at this and take it from here!

**FAST Search Query Integration Overview**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394628.aspx#int_overview_web_service

**EDIT**

make sure you follow this to rule out any possibilities:

http://sharepointconnoisseur.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/why-sharepoint-2010-search-does-not.html

I have a feeling that its probably got todo with a premission issue as its added to the serach index but not showing the content! what account are you running under?

just to outline the differences:

[image]

fast can be customised to do a deep search including all the files you noted!

http://searchunleashed.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/reasons-to-go-with-fast-search-for-sharepoint-instead-of-regular-sharepoint-2010-search/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I've tried changing this option but it didn't have any effect unfortunately :( I'm not sure I see how the FAST search query integration will help with indexing problems?

Comment: just ammended my answer

Comment: Thanks. The service is running as 'Network Service'. I don't think this is a permissions issue as the permissions for these files are the same as the permissions for other files which are indexed correctly. I'll go through the advice in the link your provided and see if any helps.